# How can i do the following in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create a simple course registration web site in asp.net. I am now creating a page that allows a user to create a course. Here is the related user interface:

[image]

And here is the code of this page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AdminCreateCourse.aspx.cs"
Inherits="AdminCreateCourse" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        font-size: x-large;
    }
    .style3
    {
        font-size: small;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="style1">
    <strong>Create Course</strong></div>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    Instructor Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dInstructorSelect" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="FullName" Height="16px" Width="202px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"

        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] + ' ' + [Surname] as FullName FROM [InstructorTable] ORDER BY [Name]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<p>
    Course Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tCourseName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Course ID<br />
    (Subject/Course):&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dSubject" runat="server" Width="70px">
        <asp:ListItem>CS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>CULT</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ECON</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>IS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>MAN</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>SPS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>VACD</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>BIO</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>EE</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>EL</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>MAT</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ME</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>MS</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>TE</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tCourse" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    CRN:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tCRN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Level:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dLevel" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Undergraduate</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Graduate</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<p>
    Term:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</p>
<p>
    Course Description:
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="tCourseDescription" runat="server" Height="138px" Width="406px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Capacity:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tCapacity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    Class Hour and Day: <span class="style3">Start Hour:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dHourStart" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>8:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>13:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>14:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>15:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>17:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>18:40</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>19:40</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp; End Hour:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dHourEnd" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>10:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>13:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>14:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>15:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>17:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>18:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>19:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>20:30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9:30</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp; Day:</span> &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="dDay" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Monday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Tuesday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Wednesday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Thursday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Friday</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="bAddCourseHour" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="bAddCourseHour_Click" />
</p>
<p>
    Prerequisites:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tPreq1" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tPreq2" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="tPreq3" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<asp:Button ID="bSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="bSubmit_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="bClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="bClear_Click" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, a course may be held in more than one different days, but my interface only allows one day. Should i handle this using AJAX, or is there any other way? If i should use ajax, how can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a way to allow multiple selections on the "Day" field. If so, you have at least couple of options here:

1) Either use the CheckBoxList Control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/enIN/library/8bw4x4wa(v=vs.90).aspx). 
2) Or, if real estate is an issue, use the DropDownCheckBoxes control at http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/

Comment: Disadvantage of changing the dropdown into a checkboxlist: you can specify just one start/endtime for all selected days.

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I am looking for a way to allow multiple day and hour selections. For example, a lecture may be on mondays between 10 and 11, and also on fridays between 9 and 10.